# Merge duplicate values in columns

Tags: text-processing, csv-simple

Given a file like this

```
value,value,value,value
value1,value1,value,value1
value2,value2,value,value2
```

How can I transform it to look like this:

```
value,value,value,value
value1,value1,    ,value1
value2,value2,    ,value2
```

Basically, to merge duplicate values in column 3 and present it in first row and retain other data, also make this as one record within csv.

I have tried `cat file | sort -u -t, -k3` but it does not work.

Comment: The logic is: of 3th column = 3th column in 1st row. But what to do if they are not =?

Comment: What happens if the 3rd column in the 10th row is the same as the 3rd column in the 9th row, but different to the 3rd column in the first row?

Comment: Will all the values of the first row always be the same?

Comment: what do you mean _`also make this as one record within csv.`_? please also considering above comments as well as read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then [edit] your question to clarify it more.

Answer (score 1):

### With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
perl -F, -e '
    do{ $col = $F[2]; print; next } if $.==1;
    $F[2] = " "x4 if $F[2] eq $col;
    print join ",", @F
' file
```

### With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk '
    BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
    {if (NR==1) col=$1;
    else if($3 == col) $3="    "}
    1
' file
```

### Output

```
value,value,value,value
value1,value1,    ,value1
value2,value2,    ,value2
```

Comment: This only works if all the values on the first line are the same. Which is what the OP has shown, but not what they describe. No idea if this is a problem or not.

Comment: Post edited accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Not just for column 3

```bash
$ cat file.csv
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd
aat,bbk,ccc,ddd
aaa,bbk,cc3,dd4
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd

$ awk '
      BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","}
      NR == 1 {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) prev[i] = $i}
      NR > 1 {
          for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
              if ($i == prev[i])
                  gsub(/./, " ", $i)
              else
                  prev[i] = $i
      }
      1
  ' file.csv
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd
aat,bbk,   ,
aaa,   ,cc3,dd4
   ,bbb,ccc,ddd
```

Comment: this doesn't remove duplicates in 3rd column only (and yes, as you mentored it does remove in all columns) and also that is not removing _all_ duplicates but instead, it removes consecutive duplicates within each column (something like what `uniq` do on an unsorted data). so you may want to mention that in your answer or change your command to remove all duplicates in each columns

Comment: All true. Which of our assumptions are correct is still a pending question.